# jQuery append not inserting detached elements

Tags: jquery, append, detach, enquire.js

I can't seem to get append working for elements I am detaching with detach()

Basically what I want to do is remove some images from the DOM based on screen size (larger than 900px) and add them back (smaller than 900px). I am using [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) to handle the breakpoints but I am unable to properly implement the insertion of the removed elements.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="mobile-slides">
  <a><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
  <a><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
  <a><img src="image2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Here's the js I'm using:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 900px)", {
    match : function() {
        var slides = $('.mobile-slides a').detach();
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        $('.mobile-slides').append(slides);
    }
});
```

Detach seems to be working but when the second condition is met nothing is happening. Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**
Stupid mistake on my behalf I was only declaring the variable "slides" inside the enquire match function therefore it wasn't available to the unmatch function.

This now works:

```
var slides = $('.mobile-slides a');
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 900px)", {
    match : function() {
        $('.mobile-slides a').detach();
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        $('.mobile-slides').append(slides);
    }
});
```

I could also use remove() it seems instead of detach()

Comment: can you provide a fiddle the reproduces the problem?

Comment: Try `console.log(slides);` just before `append();` to see whether you are giving something to be appended..

Comment: it looks like a scoping issue of the variable `slides`, you need to share more code

Comment: Sorry guys the original question probably wasn't specific enough I've updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
slides.appendTo( '.mobile-slides' );
```

sample code for button click ,

```
var slides;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if ( slides ) {
    slides.appendTo( ".mobile-slides" );
    slides = null;
  } else {
    slides = $('.mobile-slides a').detach();
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that in here `slides` variable is used as a toggle from `null` to an actual element array.  The `if` statement makes this work, otherwise, it would be useless!